# multilline use of object methods

Tags: multimethod

I have a question that's nagging me.
Is it possible to use multiple methods of an
instance , without writing the name. I dont
mean static methods.

Language : java

For example: object name bibo of class manager

```
         the class has three methods
         - fire
         - hiring
         - raise
```

And what i want is like this:

```
         bibo.fire();
             .hiring();
             .raise();
```

I'm asking cause I saw this in another project, but cant recall how it was done or what project it was.